# is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Tags: api, youtube, cors

I am trying to send request from local server to youtube server bu the chrome console is displaying the following error

**is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin**
Code is

```
http.open("POST", url, true);
    http.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "AuthSub token=" + AccessToken);
    http.setRequestHeader("GData-Version", 2);
    http.setRequestHeader("X-GData-Key", "key=" + dev_key);
    http.setRequestHeader("Content-Length", sendXML.length);
    http.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/atom+xml; charset=UTF-8");



    http.onreadystatechange = function() 
    {
        if(http.readyState == 4) {
            alert(http.responseXML);
            alert(http.responseText);
            document.getElementById("response").innerHTML=http.getAllResponseHeaders();
        }
    }
    http.send(sendXML);
```

It will be done by implementing JSONP callback function. But I do not have idea how to implement it
plz guide me

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot use XMLHttpRequest against the YouTube API because of the browser's [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy). Instead, you should use the YouTube API's json-p functionality:

http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_json.html

**EDIT:** As of May 18, 2012, the YouTube API supports CORS: http://apiblog.youtube.com/2012/05/unlocking-javascripts-potential-with.html